# extracting pairs in which y-component has a relative maximum value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of several pairs. You can find it [here](https://xfl.jp/J81IH6) or create it manually. Applying `ListPlot` on the intended list results in the below plot:

[image: myplot]

How do I extract the maximum pairs `(x,y)`, whose `y` components are recognizable in the plot, from the list as an individual list.

Comment: This would seem the be a perfect application for FindPeaks.  Have you tried this?

Comment: It is a good comment but we reach the positions of peaks and the value of them. We should extract the exact value of the `x` components in lieu of their positions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For finding the position and the values of the peaks:

```
peakPosValues = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]]], 1];
%\\TableForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> 0.&1.\\ 4.4&0.982211\\ 8.9&0.961575\\ 13.3&0.942571\\ 17.8&0.923857\\ \
> 22.2&0.906203\\ 25.1&0.046994
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
ListPlot[{data, peakPosValues}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}]
```

> [image]

If you don't want the last "peak" on the bottom right, replace the PeakDetect options as follows:

```
peakPosValues = Pick[data, PeakDetect[data[[;; , 2]], 1, 0, .8], 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for maxima near the peaks in the data ...

We can find peaks in the data using FindPeaks:

```
ipeak = Most@FindPeaks[irawd[[All, 2]], .5];
ipeak = irawd[[#]] & /@ ipeak[[All, 1]]
```

`ipeak` corresponds to @Fraccolo's answer.

We can find maxima near these peaks after interpolating, then using `FindMaximum`:

```
intrp = Interpolation[irawd];
apeak = ipeak;
Quiet@Do[
  v = ipeak[[jp, 1]];
  p = FindMaximum[intrp[t], {t, v}];
  apeak[[jp]] = {t /. p[[2]], p[[1]]},
  {jp, 2, Length@ipeak}
  ]
```

so that `apeak` are the real peaks.  We can compare peaks in the measured data with those in the 'real' function using

```
tabl = Partition[Flatten@Transpose[{ipeak, apeak}], 4];
TableForm[tabl,
 TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"Data X", "Data Peak", "Interp. X", 
    "Interp. Peak"}}]
```

[image]

Based on the similarity between your data and the underlying function, it would seem that you've sampled things very well.

Graphically ...

```
iepl = {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[#]} & /@ ipeak;
aepl = {Blue, PointSize[.01], Point[#]} & /@ apeak;
Plot[intrp[t], {t, 0, irawd[[-1, 1]]},
 Epilog -> {iepl, aepl}]
```

[image]